# How to Position an Image underneath a form in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a login page and I would to position a custom image border to the center underneath the form.

The image is not positioning to the `margin-left` properly.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Below is the code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
 * {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
#username {
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-bottom: inherit;
  margin-right: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  border: 0px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#username:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#password {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: inherit;
  margin-right: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  border: 0px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#password:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#submit {
  margin-top: 35px;
  border: 0;
  background: url(submit1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
}
#submit:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#submit:hover {
  background-image: url(submit2.png);
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-top: 17em;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="login">
    <form action="Scripts/xxx.php">
      <img src="border_transparent.png">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter  Username" />
      <br>
      <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Secret Password" />
      <br>
      <button id="submit" value="" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy; Project Blackhat Operatives 2015</div>
```

This is currently how my page looks: http://s7.postimg.org/vvfi8m1uj/Screen_Shot_2015_01_11_at_7_07_21_PM.png

This is what I am trying for the page to look like: http://s11.postimg.org/avy2caylv/Screen_Shot_2015_01_11_at_7_09_01_PM.png

Comment: can you explain this differently? or create an image of what you're looking to do?

Comment: you've posted the same image twice

Comment: I apologize @adriano66. I posted the correct image this time.

Comment: @jmore009 i posted a concept sketch and what the page actually looks like at the moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is centered, the issue is the background image behind it that you are absolute positioning. That isn't centered, you can add `left: 50%` and a negative margin to bring it back to the center (`left` positions it from the corner not the center):

```
img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%; //add
  margin: 200px 0 0 -175px; //add
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rc1f27bo/)

What you should be doing though is adding that image as a `background-image` to either your `form` or `#login` containers. Positioning an `img` tag is not a great way of handling this.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem. I will keep the background-image in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#submit:hover {
background-image: url("submit2.png");
}
```

Need quotes/double quotes.

Comment: I dont think thats the issue. OP didnt mention a broken image path